# Any suggestions on how to change this class for reading Strings instead of doubles?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, alphabetical

In classroom we made this class that sorts doubles and arranges them from min. to max. I'm interested in changing this class to read from a text file with names and sort them alphabetically instead of doubles that it reads from a numbers text file.

```java
package versionDouble;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Datos {

    double[]  datos; 


    public Datos(String fileString) {

        int cuantos = contarDatos( fileString );

        this.datos = new double[ cuantos ];

        leerDatos( fileString );

    } // Datos


    private void leerDatos(String fileString) {

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileString));

            for (int i = 0; i < this.datos.length; i++) {

                this.datos[i] = scanner.nextDouble();

            } // for

            scanner.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } // leerDatos


    } // Datos class 


    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        String string = "";

                string = Arrays.toString( this.datos ); 

        return string;

    } // toString


    private int contarDatos(String fileString) {


        int contador = 0;

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File(fileString));

            while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {

                scanner.nextDouble();

                contador++;

            } // while

            scanner.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } // catch

        return contador;

    } // contarDatos


    public void selectionSort() {


        for (int  startScan = 0;  startScan < this.datos.length;  startScan++) {

            int minIndex = startScan;

            double minValue = this.datos[ minIndex ]; 

            for (int index = 0; index < this.datos.length; index++) {

                if( this.datos[ index ] < minValue) {

                    minIndex = index;
                    minValue = this.datos[ index ];

                } // if

            } // for interno

            if(  minIndex != startScan  ) {

                double temporary = this.datos[startScan];

                this.datos[ startScan ] = this.datos[ minIndex ];

                this.datos [ minIndex ] = temporary;

            } // swap

        } // for externo

        Arrays.sort( this.datos );

    } // selectionSort

} //  Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call a different member function on `Scanner`, for example `next()` or `nextLine()`. Also, change the data type of several variables to store strings instead of floating-point numbers. Also you will have to find a way to compare the string alphabetically instead of numerically.

Comment: I already did the first two things you suggested but the third one, "find a way to compare the string alphabetically instead of numerically", that's where I'm lost.

Comment: Try looking at the string class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the most efficient, a quick solution would be that one could just call `String.value(double d);` and get the String representation of the double!

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      double d = 102939939.939;
      System.out.println("Return Value : " + String.valueOf(d) );

   }
}
```

Output:
`Return Value : 1.02939939939E8`